# Clone an Objects Properties

Tags: c#, listview, object, clone

I am attempting to clone all the properties of a `ListView` so that I don't have to go in and copy each one separately with a line of code but after numerous attempts, I have failed to get it working. 
I now get the error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Is my understanding of how properties are set all wrong?

```
private ListView generateEmptyClone(ListView toClone)
{
    ListView newCopy = new ListView();

    foreach (var propToClone in toClone.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = newCopy.GetType().GetProperty(propToClone.Name);
        if (propInfo.CanWrite)
            propInfo.SetValue(newCopy, propToClone.GetValue(toClone, null));
    }

    return newCopy;
}
```

Comment: Probably trying to read some private property? I guess your `TargetInvocationException` has an inner exception that shows you what actually went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As René Vogt mentions in his comment, use are accessing private properties. Use the [BindingFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) to limit the properties to those you really need.

Answer (score 0):

The [`PropertyInfo.CanWrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property only tells you if the property has a setter. It does not tell you if the property is `public`.

You should only enumerate the `public` instance properties like this:

```
foreach (var propToClone in toClone.GetType().
              GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
{
    PropertyInfo propInfo = newCopy.GetType().GetProperty(propToClone.Name);
    if (propInfo.CanWrite)
        propInfo.SetValue(newCopy, propToClone.GetValue(toClone, null));
}
```

The `static` properties are already equal for all `ListView` instances, so you don't need to enumerate them.

---

Though it *is* possible to set `private` fields via reflection (using [`GetFields()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc(v=vs.110).aspx)) I don't think this is necessary in your case, as you probably only want to clone "normal" `ListView` properties.

If you still get that `TargetInvocationException` there might be another problem. `TargetInvocationException`s normally have an `InnerException` that tells you what exactly went wrong. For example, if you **clone the `SelectedIndex`property before you clone the `Items`** this may cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. But cloning hte `Items` may itself be error prone.